# error when booting image transferred with bmaptool but dd works

Tags: yocto, mender

**FWIW:** I searched StackOverflow for bmaptool-related issues and only found 5 posts, none of which matched my issue. If I'm in the wrong place, I'm sure someone can tell me where to go ;)

```
Results for bmaptool
5 results
```

Using Yocto I have built an image file (`.sdimg` encompassing 4 partitions for a Mender install) with associated `sdimg.bz2` and `sdimg.bmap` files. System is Freescale ARMv8a NXP iMX.8+ and the image builds fine — and usually boots fine.

```
IF (I boot from USB drive and use dd to transfer the file to eMMC) THEN
    when I shutdown, remove the USB drive, and try to boot from eMMC
    -> everything works just fine
```

```
IF (I boot from USB drive and use bmaptool to transfer the file to eMMC) THEN
    when I shutdown, remove the USB drive, and try to boot from eMMC
    -> sometimes it gives me an "unaligned pointer" error and won't boot
```

This *appears* as if something isn't right in bmaptool (since the same image works with dd) but that seems improbable given how many people are likely using bmaptool and how long it has been around ...

*Sooooo, any thoughts on what I may be doing wrong?*

Regards,
k

***action, expectation, reality***

- built a Yocto image configured for Mender and used bmaptool to flash eMMC with the bz2 file
- expected the image to boot successfully — just like it does when transferring the same image file with dd
- occasionally the boot halts with a "misaligned pointer" error

---

NOTE to the Monitors: not being allowed to "tag" a question with an accurate descriptor of the core question being asked ([bmaptool](/questions/tagged/bmaptool)) is not very helpful ... it simply prevents others from finding it, because the problem is only peripherally related to the "accepted" tags of [yocto](/questions/tagged/yocto) (the build environment) and [mender](/questions/tagged/mender) (the reason for building the image in the first place).

The "advice" says to create tags about darn-near-anything in order to "help others" (specifically it says "*Tag things in more than one way so people can find them more easily. **Add tags for product lines, projects, teams, and the specific technologies or languages used**.*" But obviously this is bogus, because **it won't let someone do so** without already being beyond the point of asking basic questions.

Comment: could you share the bmap commands you're using?
You can read the wic file with 'wic ls the_wic_file.wic'.  or 'wic ls the_wic_file.wic:1' for the first partition